# Set object property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I am not sure it is possible but you guys can say it:

```
 var tricky = function(obj){
 var ret = new Object();
 ret.porp1 = 'undefined';
 ret.prop2 = 'undefined';
 for (porp in ret){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) == false){
        obj.???????? = prop;
 }
 return obj;
 }

 tricky({prop1:'ok_prop'});

 ===>>{prop1:'ok_prop',prop2:'undefined'}
```

I did not put the question in words because I find it hard to define properly. My problem is as you can see: I have an object and sometimes I set some properties in that object sometimes do not. I want a function which will check if my object has a range of properties and if not then set it explicitly to undefined. It does not work if I leave it implicitly undefined, since I use it to send it to a jade template which might have a property set to a value but the system has changed state and I want it to be a undefined.

What should I put after the `obj.[what I put here]` to be set at first to porp1 then prop2.

Comment: possibly whatever your trying to ask is because; `porp != prop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to add members of the "template" object `ret` to `obj` if they do not exist & that `porp` is a typo.

You say that if they do not exist you want to *set it explicitly to undefined* however there is no need as a non-existent member of an object is already undefined:

```
 var x = new Object(); 
 alert (typeof x.wibble === 'undefined') //true
```

Your `ret.porp1 = 'undefined';` is assigning a **string** object with the textual content  `'undefined'` to the member, this has nothing to do with the state of being "undefined", if this is your intention:

```
var tricky = function(obj) {
    var ret = {
        prop1: 'undefined',
        prop2: 'undefined'
    }
    for (requiredMember in ret) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(requiredMember) === false) {
            obj[requiredMember] = ret[requiredMember];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var o = {prop1:'ok_prop'};

o = tricky(o);

console.dir(o);
  Object
    prop1: "ok_prop"
    prop2: "undefined"
```

Comment: FYI [undefined](http://scottdowne.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/javascript-typeof-undefined-vs-undefined/). You gave me an answer to my question, though I still have a problem. I will accept it, since it was to the question, but the undefined thing is more complicated.